# Folland real analysis 9.11

Tags: distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis

This comes from question 9.11 of Folland's Real analysis textbook. Unfortunately, I have no idea to how to start with this question. So can some one help me with part $a$?

For part $a$, I can not come up with any theorems which relate the distribution to the derivative of the test function, except the definition of derivative on distribution, which does not seems to be useful in solving this question.

BTW, the support is defined to be the complement of the maximal open subset of $R^n$ on which $F$ is $0$.

[image]

Update: I can solve part $a, b, c$ now. Can someone point out how to deal with part $d$?

I think I forgot an important fact that $<\delta,\phi>= \phi(0)$ in proving part d, and that is how the question get the $\delta$ function...

Comment: For (a), you'll want to use Proposition 5.15.

Comment: @OpenSeason  Thanks a lot! It seems that 5.15 is an extremely useful theorem...

Comment: It is very useful, it generalizes the continuity of linear operators in locally convex spaces, thanks to that theorem understand the continuous inclusions in locally convex spaces, and in particular in Fréchet spaces.

Comment: I think you can prove (b) using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule#Multivariable_calculus) to explicitly calculate the deriviative of $\phi_k$. And (d) follows from (c) plus [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor.27s_theorem_for_multivariate_functions).  I myself haven't figured out (c).

Comment: @OpenSeason I think I forgot an important fact that $<\delta,\phi>= \phi(0)$ in proving part d, and that is how the question gets the $\delta$ function...

Comment: @ask Yep that'll do it.

Comment: Hi, can either of you explain how to attack part d? I dont see how Taylor's theorem and part c) can apply.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody answer this question formally, I post my solutions here. Any comments are welcomed.

(a). Choose function $\psi$ such that $\psi(x)=1$ for $|x|\le \frac{1}{2}$ and $\psi(x)=0$ for $|x|\ge 1$, then $$|\langle F,\phi\rangle|=|\langle F,\psi\phi\rangle+\langle F,(1-\psi)\phi\rangle|=|\langle F,\psi\phi\rangle|,$$ since $supp(F)=\{0\}$. And $$ |\langle F,\psi\phi\rangle|\le C\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup_{|x|\le 1}|\partial^{\alpha}(\psi\phi)(x)|\le C^{'}\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup_{|x|\le 1}|\partial^{\alpha}\phi(x)|$$ for some constants $C,C^{'},N$, by Proposition 5.15 and the product rule for derivatives.

(b). Obviously, $\phi_k(x)=\phi(x)$ when $x\ge\frac{2}{k}$. When $x\le\frac{2}{k}$, we can calcualte by the hint and the product rule for derivatives as follows, \begin{eqnarray*}
\partial^{\alpha}(\phi_k-\phi)&=&\sum_{\beta+\gamma=\alpha}A_{\beta,\gamma}k^{|\gamma|}\partial^{\beta}\phi(x)\partial^{\gamma}\psi(kx)\\
&\le&\sum_{\beta+\gamma=\alpha}B_{\beta,\gamma}k^{|\gamma|}|x|^{N+1-|\beta|}\partial^{\gamma}\psi(kx)\\
&\le&\sum_{\beta+\gamma=\alpha}C_{\beta,\gamma}k^{|\alpha|-(N+1)}\\
&\le&k^{-1}\sum_{\beta+\gamma=\alpha}D_{\beta,\gamma}\\
\end{eqnarray*}
where the $A_{\beta,\gamma},B_{\beta,\gamma},C_{\beta,\gamma},D_{\beta,\gamma}$ are some constants. The results follows.

(c). By (a),  \begin{eqnarray*}
|\langle F,\phi\rangle|&=&|\langle F,\phi-\phi_k\rangle|\\
&\le&C\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\sup_{|x|\le 1}|\partial^{\alpha}(\phi-\phi_k)(x)|\rightarrow0\quad(k\rightarrow+\infty).
\end{eqnarray*}

(d).It would be easy to construct functions $\{f_{\alpha}\}_{|\alpha|\le N}$ such that $$\partial^{\alpha}f_{\beta}(0)=\delta_{\alpha\beta},\quad|\alpha|,|\beta|\le N $$
For example, the function $h=\int_0^x e^{-1/|t|^2}dt$ satisfy $h(0)=0, h^{'}(0)=1, h^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k\ge 2$.

Since $\partial^{\beta}(\phi-\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\partial^{\alpha}\phi(0)f_{\alpha})=0$ when $|\beta|\le N $ ,by (c) we have $$0=\langle F,\phi-\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\partial^{\alpha}\phi(0)f_{\alpha}\rangle=\langle F,\phi\rangle-\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\langle F, f_{\alpha}\rangle\partial^{\alpha}\delta(\phi)$$

Thus, $\langle F,\phi\rangle=\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}\langle F, f_{\alpha}\rangle\partial^{\alpha}\delta(\phi).$ Define $c_{\alpha}=\langle F, f_{\alpha}\rangle$ and we complete the proof.

Comment: For (d), define $f_{\alpha} := \xi(x) \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha !}$ where $\xi \in C^\infty_c$ where $\xi(x) = 1$ on $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: @Luke Yes! That's a good one.